# pyserial on Windows with PyPy

Tags: python, pyserial, pypy

I'm trying to run pyserial while using PyPy on Windows 8 but every time I try to call serial.write() it fails with:

```
SerialException: WriteFile failed (WindowsError(0, 'The operation completed successfully'))
```

Fun how it fails successfully :P

Anyone have success running pyserial in PyPy on Windows?

Comment: ctypes.GetLastError() is returning 0 in this library because this library is buggy according to the ctypes manual, but in a way that still works as expected most of the times on CPython.  I'm trying to figure out if and how we can fix PyPy to be bug-to-bug compatible, see https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issue/1944/ctypes-on-windows-getlasterror-not-working .  This doesn't really answer your question, but at least it should fix the error message and give us a clue about what the real error is.

Comment: Just encountered this error in CPython, so it's not PyPy specific.